# Where should store dispatch for async actions be made in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

Hope this doesn't count as an "opinion" question. I'm following [this](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/react-redux-tutorial-part-iii-async-redux/) tutorial and this person calls `store.dispatch(loadCats())` in their `src/index.js` file - the entry point. I have the following file structure (which is largely the same as the one in the tutorial).

```
.
├── README.md
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
└── src
    ├── actions
    │   ├── actionTypes.js
    │   └── partActions.js
    ├── api
    │   └── partApi.js
    ├── components
    │   ├── App
    │   │   ├── index.css
    │   │   ├── index.js
    │   │   └── index.test.js
    │   ├── Header
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   └── ThingCard
    │       ├── index.css
    │       └── index.js
    ├── containers
    │   └── ThingsGrid
    │       ├── index.css
    │       └── index.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── pages
    │   ├── DragonsPage
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   ├── ThingsPage
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   └── KittensPage
    │       └── index.js
    ├── reducers
    │   ├── initialState.js
    │   ├── partsReducer.js
    │   └── rootReducer.js
    ├── routes.js
    └── store
        └── configureStore.js
```

I have these `pages` which are containers for containers. In other words, a page can have multiple containers related to some logical category like `Thing`, `Kitten`, or `Dragon`. It makes sense for me to call functions like `store.dispatch(loadThings())` from each `page`. Is this a common pattern or am I miss understanding something?

```
    // src/index.js
    const store = configureStore()
    store.dispatch(loadParts())

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>
        </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

This is how I pass the store into the routes using `react-redux`. If it is okay to dispatch actions in my `page` components, how would I access this store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all, to access your store from your Component page, you can use `mapStateToProps` redux method. Usually you leave the dispatch function inside the reducer OR you create a `action folder` only to execute actions before calling the reducer switch. I didnt get why you want to access this store folder.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class ExampleComponent extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.exampleAsyncFunction()
  }

  render() {
  return <p> 'anything' </p>
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    admin: state.admin,
  })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  exampleAsyncFunction: reqObj => {
    dispatch(adminActions.exampleAsyncFunction())  
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ExampleComponent)
```

Comment: I'm confused about the terms `action folder` and `store folder`. Also, what good does it do to dispatch actions inside a reducer? My reasoning was, instead of loading every resource from the server at application load, when a `SomePage` dispatches fetch action -> reducer consumes it -> page gets resource in its props -> page passes resource to container

Comment: Also, I didn't know that's how `mapDispatchToProps` was used - so that's working fine, thank you! Would like some clarification on the things mentioned above ^